# Function that sums previous N observations

Tags: r

I would like to find an efficient way to sum the number of points that a team received in the previous N matches (not including the points in the current match) for every combination of simulation_ID, team and season. If a team played less than N matches so far, the function should return NA.

A simplified data set:

| match_ID | season | simulation_ID | home_team | team | match_result | team_points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 1 | TRUE | Manchester Utd | Home win | 3 |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 2 | TRUE | Manchester Utd | Draw | 1 |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 3 | TRUE | Manchester Utd | Home win | 3 |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 1 | FALSE | Tottenham | Home win | 0 |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 2 | FALSE | Tottenham | Home win | 0 |
| 1 | 2015-2016 | 3 | FALSE | Tottenham | Away win | 3 |
| 2 | 2015-2016 | 1 | TRUE | Leicester | Home win | 3 |
| 2 | 2015-2016 | 2 | TRUE | Leicester | Home win | 3 |
| 2 | 2015-2016 | 3 | TRUE | Leicester | Away win | 0 |
| 2 | 2015-2016 | 1 | FALSE | Sunderland | Draw | 1 |

The expected output is an extra column in the data, called 'accumulated_team_points' that returns the points in the last N matches for that team, season and simulation_ID.

I seem not to be able to find a way to do this.

Comment: Please show the expected ouptut

Comment: I have edited my question, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Tor97, the intent is that you show what you think an operation like that should end up providing as its results. If you see my answer, I demonstrate that even in a seemingly simple question like this, there are options that produce different output. In good questions on SO, one will often find attempted code, sample data, expected output given that sample data, and often the warnings/errors that are problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two operations here: grouping (I'll demonstrate with `dplyr`) and a rolling-window summation (I'll use `zoo`).

Also, your data is a little too sparse to be very awesome grouping by all three of `team, season, simulation_ID`, so I'll just show grouping by `team` this time. For your larger data, replace `group_by(team)` with `group_by(team, season, simulation_ID)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
k <- 3 # window size
dat %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(accumulated_team_points = zoo::rollapply(team_points, k, FUN = sum, align = "right", fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 8
#    match_ID season    simulation_ID home_team team           match_result team_points accumulated_team_points
#       <int> <chr>             <int> <lgl>     <chr>          <chr>              <int>                   <int>
#  1        1 2015-2016             1 TRUE      Manchester Utd Home win               3                      NA
#  2        1 2015-2016             2 TRUE      Manchester Utd Draw                   1                      NA
#  3        1 2015-2016             3 TRUE      Manchester Utd Home win               3                       7
#  4        1 2015-2016             1 FALSE     Tottenham      Home win               0                      NA
#  5        1 2015-2016             2 FALSE     Tottenham      Home win               0                      NA
#  6        1 2015-2016             3 FALSE     Tottenham      Away win               3                       3
#  7        2 2015-2016             1 TRUE      Leicester      Home win               3                      NA
#  8        2 2015-2016             2 TRUE      Leicester      Home win               3                      NA
#  9        2 2015-2016             3 TRUE      Leicester      Away win               0                       6
# 10        2 2015-2016             1 FALSE     Sunderland     Draw                   1                      NA
```

That defaults to `NA` for the first `k-1` instances in a window, which is usually a sane and defensible default. If, however, you want to sum even partial sums, then replace `fill=NA` with `partial=TRUE`:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(team) %>%
  mutate(accumulated_team_points = zoo::rollapply(team_points, k, FUN = sum, align = "right", partial = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 x 8
#    match_ID season    simulation_ID home_team team           match_result team_points accumulated_team_points
#       <int> <chr>             <int> <lgl>     <chr>          <chr>              <int>                   <int>
#  1        1 2015-2016             1 TRUE      Manchester Utd Home win               3                       3
#  2        1 2015-2016             2 TRUE      Manchester Utd Draw                   1                       4
#  3        1 2015-2016             3 TRUE      Manchester Utd Home win               3                       7
#  4        1 2015-2016             1 FALSE     Tottenham      Home win               0                       0
#  5        1 2015-2016             2 FALSE     Tottenham      Home win               0                       0
#  6        1 2015-2016             3 FALSE     Tottenham      Away win               3                       3
#  7        2 2015-2016             1 TRUE      Leicester      Home win               3                       3
#  8        2 2015-2016             2 TRUE      Leicester      Home win               3                       6
#  9        2 2015-2016             3 TRUE      Leicester      Away win               0                       6
# 10        2 2015-2016             1 FALSE     Sunderland     Draw                   1                       1
```

FYI: I'm assuming that the data is pre-ordered.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(match_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), season = c("2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016", "2015-2016"), simulation_ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), home_team = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), team = c("Manchester Utd", "Manchester Utd", "Manchester Utd", "Tottenham", "Tottenham", "Tottenham", "Leicester", "Leicester", "Leicester", "Sunderland"), match_result = c("Home win", "Draw", "Home win", "Home win", "Home win", "Away win", "Home win", "Home win", "Away win", "Draw"), team_points = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Incredible, exactly what I needed! Thank you. I will remember 'rollapply'.

Comment: Could shorten rolling part to: `zoo::rollsumr(team_points, k, fill = NA)`